# tcpreplay output to STDOUT?

Tags: openbsd, tcpdump

```
$ tcpreplay tcpdump-2015-01-02-18h-13m.pcap        
ERROR:  The intf1 option is required
tcpreplay (tcpreplay) - Replay network traffic stored in pcap files
USAGE:  tcpreplay [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]... <pcap_file(s)>

   -q, --quiet                Quiet mode
   -T, --timer=str            Select packet timing mode: select, ioport, rdtsc, gtod, nano, abstime
       --sleep-accel=num      Reduce the amount of time to sleep by specified usec
       --rdtsc-clicks=num     Specify the RDTSC clicks/usec
   -v, --verbose              Print decoded packets via tcpdump to STDOUT
   -A, --decode=str           Arguments passed to tcpdump decoder
   -K, --enable-file-cache    Enable caching of packets to internal memory
       --preload-pcap         Preloads packets into RAM before sending
   -c, --cachefile=str        Split traffic via a tcpprep cache file
   -i, --intf1=str            Server/primary traffic output interface
   -I, --intf2=str            Client/secondary traffic output interface
       --listnics             List available network interfaces and exit$ 
$ pkg_info | grep tcpreplay
tcpreplay-3.4.4p1   resend network traffic saved by tcpdump
$ uname -a
OpenBSD notebook.lan 5.6 GENERIC.MP#333 amd64
$
```

Since wireshark is too resource hungry, I need to see the packets in tcpreplay, just like in wireshark. **Q:** How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpreplay` is the wrong tool. Its job is to generate packets and send them to the network, not display their contents to stdout.

If Wireshark (including its command-line utility `tshark`) is considered too resource hungry for you, then probably the only other option is `tcpdump`. Be aware that its packet decoding capabilities are not as rich as Wireshark's, but then... those extra capabilities are what make Wireshark heavier.